# Issue with identifying the minimal representation of state

Tags: reactjs, redux

As the ReactJS (and other flux implementations, such as redux) recommended:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state

We should’t keep a state which can be computed from other state(we call it derived data), otherwise when we set a state, we have to set another.

But consider the example below:

> There are 2 states in my page
>
> 1. The color of traffic light: *light = red / green*
> 2. Are there any people coming across the road: *people = true*(there are people) / *false* (no people)
>
> As we know, people can't come across the road when the traffic light is red.
>
> So, we have 3 normal combined states:
>
> 1. *light = green and people = true*
> 2. *light = green and people = false*
> 3. *light = red and people = false*
>
> The other state *light = red and people = true* is invalid.
>
> We can compute *people = false* when *light = red*, in this case *people* is a derived data of *light*. But when *light = green* we can’t.

The problem is when I set the *light* value, I have to set the *people* value, otherwise it may lead to an invalid state.

So how to solve this problem? How to design my state?

Is there any library which helps managing them. First I can define the dependencies between my states. The library is response for the consistency of them. When I set a state value which is conflict with others, others will be modified to the correct one.

I wrote a simple example to show what I want, is there any library like this?

```
class ComplexState {
    constructor(config, initialState){
        this.config = config;
        this.state = initialState;

        this._checkAll();
    }

    setState(key, value){
        var config = this.config[key];
        if(config && config.type === ComplexState.Types.Enum){
            //Set Enum data type
            if(Array.isArray(config.definitionField) && config.definitionField.indexOf(value) !== -1 || 
                config.definitionField[value] && typeof config.definitionField[value].checker === 'function' && config.definitionField[value].checker(this.state)){
                //Set the value
                this.state[key] = value;
                //If there is a conflict, modify other values
                Object.keys(this.state).forEach(_key => {
                    if(key === _key){//Self
                        return;
                    }
                    var _value = this.state[_key];
                    var _config = this.config[_key];
                    if(!Array.isArray(_config.definitionField) && _config.definitionField[_value] && typeof _config.definitionField[_value].checker === 'function' && !_config.definitionField[_value].checker(this.state)){
                        //Conflict, adapt to correct value
                        this.state[_key] = _config.definitionField[_value].adapter(this.state);
                    }
                })

                //Check for conflicts
                this._checkAll();
            }else{
                //Invalid value
            }
        }
    }

    getState(){
        return Object.assign({}, this.state);
    }

    //Check for conflicts
    _checkAll(){
        Object.keys(this.state).forEach(_key => {
            var _value = this.state[_key];
            var _config = this.config[_key];
            if(!Array.isArray(_config.definitionField) && _config.definitionField[_value] && typeof _config.definitionField[_value].checker === 'function' && !_config.definitionField[_value].checker(this.state)){
                //Conflict
                throw new Error('invalid state' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
            }
        })
    }
}

ComplexState.Types = {
    Enum : 0
}
```

Use it,

```
var myStates = new ComplexState({
    light : {
        type : ComplexState.Types.Enum,
        definitionField : ['red', 'green']
    },
    people : {
        type : ComplexState.Types.Enum,
        definitionField : {
            'false' : null,
            'true' : {
                checker : function(state){
                    return state.light !== 'red';
                },
                adapter : function(state){
                    if(state.light === 'red'){
                        return 'false';
                    }
                    return state.people;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    light : 'Green',
    people : 'false'
})
console.log(myStates.getState());//{light: "Green", people: "false"}
myStates.setState('people', 'true');
console.log(myStates.getState());//{light: "Green", people: "true"}

//when I set light value to red, the people value is automatically set to false
myStates.setState('light', 'red');
console.log(myStates.getState());//{light: "red", people: "false"}
```

Comment: changing light to a bool where true is green and red is false should solve this. If you always evaluate (light && people) then the only true value is when the light is green and there are people.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what I mean. Evaluating (light && people) is meaningless, it's not an expression.  They are just 2 states in my page, and can be set independently. I have edited my description to remove the symbol &.

Comment: I understand, but what you're after is `are there people in the crossing`. What you want to do is to be able to set each value independently correct?  `are there people in the crossing` is the derived data which can always be evaluated by (light && people). Each one guards the other allowing you to mutate those two values independently in your app. The only two state values you need are light and people as long as you always derive `are there people in the crossing` from the expression (light && people).

Comment: I just want to eliminate  `each one guarding the other` with a library. I think `each one guarding the other` is always possible to produce an inconsistent state in development, just like keep 2 states, an array and its length.

Comment: This is a basic logic issue you're struggling with. If there can be no people when the light is green then you must have a bool value for people and it is impossible to logically derive what you need from just light. array.length is entirely dependent on the array itself and is completely different from your light example. Logically, to determine if people are crossing you must know if both the light is green and there are people... there is not way around that. People and light are fundamental state to your logic and both must be set.

Comment: I wrote and added a simple code which can handle this. Are there any solutions like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a library to solve this issue.
https://github.com/hanjunspirit/cascade.js

Answer (score 0):

If you need to seta value only when you set another piece of state you can do something like this:

```
this.setState({
  light: someNewColor,
  people: someNewColor === red ? false : this.state.people
});
```

If someNewColor is red, people automatically gets set to false. Otherwise it stays it's previously set value.

edit:

If you want to make this cleaner, you would have to make people and light completely independent. Ex:

```
this.setState({
  light: someNewColor
})
```

This currently doesn't work because you can't calculate the people with only the light.

Comment: This is what I want to avoid, it just like keeping 2 states: an Array and its length in the page.
`this.setState({
  list: listOfArray,
  length: listOfArray.length
});`
It may produce an inconsistent state, thus lead an error in my page.

Comment: The problem is that people it is not fully independent. It has independent parts (when the light is green) but is is also dependent on light (when it is red). There is no way to calculate the people based on the light so you must keep both. There is no way around that with this setup. In your example with the array, the length is completely dependent upon the array thus you don't need both.

Comment: I want to seek a library to help managing them. First I can define the dependencies between my states. The library is response for the consistency of my states. When I set a state value which is conflict with others, others will be modified to the correct one. I think it's possible to implement in theory.